# Android Динамическое создание меню в NavigationView

Tags: android, android-navigation-view

Пишу приложение на Android, для просмотра сериалов и т.д.
Сделал парсинг сайта и возможность переходить по сериалами и сезонам внутри них
и хочу сделать чтобы в боковом меню NavigationView появлялось меню с сериями, когда перешел к просмотру серии, т. е. досмотрел серию и не жмешь назад и потом идёшь к следующей, а открываешь меню и там выбираешь следующую.
**EDIT:** получилось найти то что хотел [ссылка на английский вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722566/dynamic-adding-item-to-navigationview-in-android)
нужно было просто взять текущее меню и к нему добавлять:

```
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
SubMenu submenu = menu.addSubMenu(Title);
submenu.add(chaptersname);
```

дальше для удаления можно использовать menu.removeItem(int id); но как получить id созданного меню?

*Вот что вышло*
[image]

**EDIT:** Можно вообще не трогать меню, а использовать headerLayout как целевое меню, а уж там можно что угодно сделать. И этот вариант конечно "не правильный" ибо это костыль и предназначение у headerLayout другое, если предложите другой вариант будет прекрасно.

Comment: а в чем вопрос?

Comment: @Cypher, как сделать чтобы в меню добавлялось новое меню, которого заранее не было.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

итак я решил вопрос:
для динамического создания меню используем SubMenu

```
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
SubMenu submenu = menu.addSubMenu(title);
submenu.add(chaptersname);
```

и потом для его удаления вот так:

```
menu.removeItem(submenu.getItem().getItemId());
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавление собственных компонентов в меню `NavigationDrawer`:

**Добавляем айтем в activity_main_drawer.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_editor"
        android:icon="@drawable/porsche"
        android:title="@string/editor" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_red_color"
        android:icon="@drawable/audi"
        android:title="@string/red_walp" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_blue_color"
        android:icon="@drawable/bugatti"
        android:title="@string/blue_walp" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_black_color"
        android:icon="@drawable/ferrari"
        android:title="@string/black_walp" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_yellow_color"
        android:icon="@drawable/lambo"
        android:title="@string/yellow_walp" />

</group>

<item android:title="@string/info">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_info"
            android:title="@string/about_us" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_license"
            android:icon="@drawable/licence_icon"
            android:title="@string/license" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

**Обрабатываем нажатие в Активити:**

```
    @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_editor) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NavActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(NavActivity.EXTRA_ID, getResources().getString(R.string.porsche));
        this.startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_red_color) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NavActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(NavActivity.EXTRA_ID, getResources().getString(R.string.audi));
        this.startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_blue_color) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NavActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(NavActivity.EXTRA_ID, getResources().getString(R.string.bugatti));
        this.startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_black_color) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NavActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(NavActivity.EXTRA_ID, getResources().getString(R.string.ferrari));
        this.startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_yellow_color) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NavActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(NavActivity.EXTRA_ID, getResources().getString(R.string.lamborghini));
        this.startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_license) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LicenseActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: обновил вопрос, нашел как добавлять, теперь надо как удалить.  есть вообще другой вариант решения, можно вообще не трогать меню, а использовать headerLayout и в нём творить что угодно..